# Convert simple CSV to list in Python 3

Tags: python, csv

I have a simple short CSV file with random words like "apple,orange,tomato" etc
When I try to convert it to a list I use this code:

```
f = open('Desktop/12.csv')
csv_f = csv.reader(f)
new_list = list(csv_f)
print (new_list)
```

But the new list looks like this: `[["apple,orange,tomato"]]`, and I can't work anymore with that until I can remove one `[` from the beginning and one `]` from the end.
Can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should specify the delimiter like this:

```
csv_f = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
```

If you want to "remove the outer `[ ]` then you do this:

```
new_list = new_list[0]
```

Comment: Did not do anything:/